# How to update webpage after automatically selecting a value from dropdown using c# webbrowser

Tags: c#, html

I've been trying to do some webpage automation using the webbrowser in c#. Normally, when I programmatically click on an element of the page, the page updates automatically in response to the given click. However, I came across a dropdownbox that does not update the webpage in response to the value selected from this box. My code for selecting the value in this box is:

```
foreach(HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
        {
            if (elem.OuterHtml.Contains("areaPanel"))
            {
                elem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "0");
            }
        }
```

When I look in my webbrowser, this code selects the correct value in the dropdownbox. But normally, when you click on this option in a normal browser like Chrome, the page updates in response to the selected value. When I do this programatically using `elem.InvokeMember("Click")`, it does not respond like normal buttons would and the page does not update. I tried to search a solution to this problem on the web, but I've exhausted the list of pages with proposed results and I'm not sure if the questions asked on these pages actually adresses the problem I present here. During the search I did find a lot of solutions that used `elem.RaiseEvent("onClick")`. But this does not seem to work either. The same for `webBrowser1.Update()`.

So my question is: if I've been able to select the proper value of the dropdownbox , why does the page not update automatically according to the selected value even after invoking a click on the element, and how can I resolve this problem using the webbrowser in c#?

Comment: Just to clarify did you want the page to postback when you selected a new element or something to happen client side with Javascript when you selected a new element?

Comment: I was trying to avoid using any Javascript because I don't really know any. But I suppose I would want a postback because now it seems the value I selected is only represented as a text and not as a 'command' to update the page, even after using InvokeMember etc., which works for other buttons but not here.

Answer (score 0):

I would have liked to have added my statement as a comment but I don't enough points so here goes.

The element you're interfacing with may use javascript, which webbrowser does not automatically handle. With webbrowser, you can [invoke the script](http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/). I personally prefer using [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) to handle webbrowser automation to keep things as close as possible to a standard browser.